# Comic book creator for Linux?

Tags: software-recommendation, ebooks

I am using https://www.pixton.com for several years now to create free comic books in Ubuntu. of course that is a website and also uses flash, but I cannot find any piece of software that allows you to create comic books in Linux. I need something similar - to have a built in sent of scenes and characters that you can manipulate to make them original. I doubt there is an app for Linux to do this but is worth asking. Thanks!

**EDIT**: I have to mention that I know about Krita, GIMP, or Blender, but none offer what Pixton does (pre-built scenes and characters that you can easily manipulate to create original scenes super fast).

Answer (score 8):

There are many programs like

- [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/)
- [Scribus](https://www.scribus.net/)
- [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) ...

But I suggest  you [**krita**](https://krita.org/en/).

Install it with

```
sudo apt install krita
```

Here I add a useful youtube-demo:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7olKdIEtNQ

If you have a character make use of [**Perspective**](https://docs.krita.org/en/general_concepts/projection/perspective.html). This makes it easy to reuse objects,...

---

If you want an even more **professional tool** use [**blender**](https://www.blender.org/)!

This program takes a long time to feel comfortable, but the results are amazing!

- [agent 327](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mN0zPOpADL4)
- [Hero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKmSdY56VtY)

There are a lot of good tutorials you can find in the web, e.g. [comic style in blender](http://www.pantherdynamics.yolasite.com/panther-dynamics-blog/comic-style-in-blender).
You can make 3d models and export it to krita. With blender you are even able to create cool movies!

This video explains how to save time by using 3d models [blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BjsHarhz0DQ).

Install it with

```
sudo apt install blender
```

Comment: Thanks. I am very familiar with GIMP and Krita, and a bit with Blender. However as I mentioned in the post I would need something that already has pre-built characters and scenes that you can manipulate (change positions, colors, facial expressions, clothing, etc.). That's what Pixton offers and makes things super easy to create comic books that look and feel original.  I am not familiar nor do I have time to draw the comic books by myself then manipulate the characters or scenes. That would be really cool, but extremely time consuming.

Comment: Modern Blender is amazing for making comics; but it's often safe to pull the most recent non-alpha from its website, instead of the older one in the package manager. End user's choice of course; but recent work on Cycles and Freestyle look very promising.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to be able to reuse as much of your work as possible, and don't want to do your compositing manually, there are a few good options.

As abu_bua mentioned, blender, krita, gimp, and similar can be used to make the un-composited pictures.  Blender and gimp even can handle the compositing, but the learning curve is steep.

For programmatic compositing, ImageMagick is pretty powerful and simple, it lets you caption, crop, matte, and combine images, the same way every time.  For something a little fancier, OpenCV is pretty incredible, and integrates well with PIL.  Together, you can join or split images, apply skew, blur, 'motion' lines, and just about anything else you can think of for compositing.

If you actually mean for creating comic books (physical paper), I highly recommend using LaTeX, it's a professional quality publishing language, capable of outputting pdfs or html.

`apt-get install imagemagick python-pil libopencv-dev python3-opencv texlive-binaries`

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned in the post I would like something similar to Pixton. They have built in scenes and characters that you can easily manipulate (change clothes, styles, colors, positions, etc.) in order to create original comic books. What you recommended are not doing that unfortunately. I may try to learn to work in Blender. Do you know any library of free blender 3D models?

Comment: I don't.  Most of what I do comes from OpenJS CAD or similar initially.  blenderartists.org has a fair amount of stuff, and there are a number of similar places you can go.